# PriorityBlockingQueue Order by Boolean Compare

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, priority-queue

```
public class CompareOrder<T extends Priority> implements Comparator<T> {

    @Override
    public int compare(T left, T right) {
        return Boolean.compare(left.getSeverity(), right.getSeverity());
    }
}
```

I have a `PriorityBlockingQueue` where I pass a Comparator:

```
new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(size, new CompareOrder());
```

I would like to order this queue based on boolean values where `true` values are first in the queue to be processed. How do I compare in `compare()` method so that true values are ordered as priority?

Comment: Could you please explain in your question what is wrong with your current code? Any errors?

Comment: Generic types need type parameters: `new CompareOrder<>()`

Comment: Not a great idea. You would be better off with two queues.

Comment: @EJP what is the idea with two queues? can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 1):

In the current implementation, `false` values will come first.
To do the reverse, you can negate the ordering:

```
class CompareOrder<T extends Priority> implements Comparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T left, T right) {
        return -Boolean.compare(left.getSeverity(), right.getSeverity());
    }
}
```

Alternatively,
you can keep the `compare` implementation the same,
but wrap your comparator in [`Collections.reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder(java.util.Comparator)):

```
new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(size, Collections.reverseOrder(new CompareOrder<>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that a Comparator works is as follows:

`left - right < 0` means that left is at the front of the queue

`left - right > 0` means that left is at the rear of the queue

If they are equal then you would return `0`.

In your case, you want the true values to be at the front of the queue. Thus, compare the two boolean values. Return `-1` or `+1` depending on which one is true and which one is false.

```
public class CompareOrder<T extends Priority> implements Comparator<T> {

    @Override
    public int compare(T left, T right) {
        if(left.getSeverity() && !right.getSeverity()){
          return -1; //push left true up the queue
        } else if(right.getSeverity() && !left.getSeverity()) {
          return 1;  //push left false down the queue
        } else {
          return 0;  //they are the same..do nothing
        }
    }

}
```